# Using Azure Quickstart Templates on Azure Government

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-gov

I'm attempting to use the 3 VM SharePoint Azure QuickStart Template on Azure Government.

Everything works fine except that the deployment errors out due to the fact that Azure Government expects the `storageAccountUri` to be `blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net`, while the default is `blob.core.windows.net`.

I've changed the `JSON files` to the expected `blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net`, but it still complains of the error that the blob URL's domain must be `blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net`.

I'm wondering why it is being overridden and how I can prevent that.

An example of the change I've made is:

```
"osDisk": {
  "name": "osdisk",
  "vhd": {
  "uri": "[concat('http://',parameters('storageAccountNamePrefix'),'1.blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net/vhds/',parameters('sqlVMName'),'-osdisk.vhd')]"
},
"caching": "ReadWrite",
"createOption": "FromImage"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the exact URL of the template that you are using? How are you executing this? Is it from PowerShell from your local machine? Or did you make these changes in your own GitHub repo?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to reference the storage account and that will ensure you always get the correct address (regardless of cloud):

```
 "osDisk": {"name": "osdisk","vhd": {"uri": "[concat(reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', 

 variables('storageAccountName')), '2015-06-15').primaryEndpoints.blob, variables('vmStorageAccountContainerName'), '/',variables('OSDiskName'),'.vhd')]"}}
```

We have some other tips for using a QuickStart that might be hard coded to a single cloud here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuregov/2016/12/02/azure-quickstart-templates/

Comment: Along with z_kramer's recommendation, there are 3 files where blob URLs are referenced:

provisioningDomainController.json (lines 70, 78 and 98),
provisioningSharepoint.json (lines 70 and 78), and
provisioningSQL.json (lines 73, 81, 91 and 111)

Comment: Thanks Zach and Milope. I tried this, but I still seem to get the same issue.
The only difference is that the template I'm using has parameters instead of variables, which I don't believe should be causing the issue. An example of my changes looks like:
 "osDisk": { "name": "osdisk", "vhd": { "uri":[concat(reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountNamePrefix')), concat('1.', '2015-06-15').primaryEndpoints.blob), '/vhds/', parameters('sqlVMName'),'-osdisk.vhd')]"},
       "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          },

Comment: If the inner concats above are resolved you may get something similar to: reference("Microsoft.Storage/storageaccounts/storageaccountname", "1.2015-06-15").primaryEndpoints.blob).

Comment: It should look more like this:

"uri": "[concat(reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/',parameters('storageAccountNamePrefix'),'1'), '2015-06-15').primaryEndpoints.blob,'vhds/',parameters('spVMName'),'-osdisk.vhd')]".

This does a reference("Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageAccountName1", "2015-06-16").primaryEndpoints.blob, which returns http s://storageAccountName1.blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net/. This then gets appended with vhds/parameters('spVMName')-osdisk.vhd. Ultimately resulting in: http s://storageAccountName1.blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net/vhds/vmname-osdisk.vhd